# Cannot catch ConnectionError with requests

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

I'm doing this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://non-existent-domain.test")
```

And getting

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='non-existent-domain.test', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10b0170f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

However, if I try to catch it like this:

```
try:
    r = requests.get("http://non-existent-domain.test")
except ConnectionError:
    print("ConnectionError")
```

Nothing changes, I still have `ConnectionError` unhandled. How to catch it properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a different `ConnectionError`. You are catching the built-in one, but `requests` has its own. So this should be

```
try:
    r = requests.get("http://non-existent-domain.test")
except requests.ConnectionError:
    print("ConnectionError")

# Output: ConnectionError
```